# Creating regions in Memcache using java

Tags: memcached

I just installed memcache in my machine.Actually,i have to create regions in there.
For eg there should be 3 regions created ,each storing a set of data.Am not sure how can i do that in memcache.Can anyone please help/give eg as it is "urgent".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Memcached itself is just a service that runs on your server.  It can be connected to and commands sent to it over a text based protocol.  Once the service is running, you can use a tool such as telnet or netcat to interact with it.

As for accessing from Java, you'll probably want a library to do most of the work for you.  There were a few listed on this question: [Java Memcached Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731738/java-memcached-client)

Now as for your regions: memchached is basically a key/value table.  To set a region you'd do something like `memcached.set("key", yourData)` and to get it back you'd do something like `yourData = memcached.get("key")`

Note that these functions will vary depending which library you are using.