# How do I view the data in memcache?

Tags: memcached

I've installed memcache and now how do I really view the data in memcache?

Is there any way to see the data present in cache inside memcache?

How do I really know whether memcache is getting data stored inside it?

Note: I don't want to write any program to see the data inside memcache. Basically, memcache server is already installed in my environment and it is caching the data as well. But I would like to know if there are any utility programs available which will show me the cached data inside memcache or if there is any command which will show me the data cached so far.

Comment: For starters you need a Java-based memcached client; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731738/java-memcached-client

Comment: Do you mean I can use client to view cached data inside memcache??

Comment: A client would seem to me to be useless if you couldn't use it for that purpose.  I would suggest you research then post a new question once you are using a client, if you continue to have problems.

Comment: I've already installed memcache server & I just want to know if there is a way to see the cached data within it. Please see my updated edits.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to get a dump of all memcached keys into a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940404/whats-the-simplest-way-to-get-a-dump-of-all-memcached-keys-into-a-file)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no way to get memcached to report which keys it holds. I believe that this was a design choice as to do so would have a negative impact on performance.

However, you can use any telnet client application to connect the memcached server and type in commands. Doing this to get or set a particular key.

For example,

```
stats
```

or:

```
get MY_KEY
```

Answer (score 11):

To dump a list of keys from a server, use `memdump` tool (sometimes `memcdump`), e.g.

```
memdump --servers=localhost
```

---

To get value of item, use `netcat`:

```
echo "get 13456_-cache-some_object" | nc 127.0.0.1 11211
```

or in Bash:

```
exec {memcache}<>/dev/tcp/localhost/11211; printf "get items:42:number\nquit\n" >&${memcache}; cat <&${memcache}
```

---

To dump all objects:

```
memdump --servers=localhost | xargs -L1 -I% sh -c 'echo "get %" | nc localhost 11211'
```

or in Bash:

```
exec {memcache}<>/dev/tcp/localhost/11211; printf "stats items\nquit\n" >&${memcache}; cat <&${memcache}
```

Comment: The binary may be named `memcdump` instead of `memdump` on your distro.

Answer (score 0):

First list the items (so we can see the ids)

```
echo "stats items" | nc 127.0.0.1 11211
```

Then you get something that looks like this:

```
STAT items:13:number 1
STAT items:13:number_hot 0
STAT items:13:number_warm 0
...
```

The id is **13** in this example. (There can be multiple ids)

Then dump data for the first 100 items for id 13:

```
echo "stats cachedump 13 100" | nc 127.0.0.1 11211
```

Then the content of an item looks like this

`ITEM sf2abhftbcvdgtegieoghetdgeddf [1302 b; 1707820192 s]`

Which tells:

- the size is 1302 bytes
- the date is 1707820192 EPOCH time -> 2024/02/13 10:29:52