# What's the simplest way to get a dump of all memcached keys into a file?

Tags: memcached

This is from just a single memcached server with around 20M keys (no expiry) and around 2G of data.

What's the easiest way to get a dump of all the key/value pairs into a flat file? I first looked at the java net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient, but this client does not support getting all keys (I think). If I had a list of all keys (which I don't), I could easily use this client to get all of the values.

I know I can get all keys using some telnet commands (e.g., telnet localhost 11211; stats items; stats cachedump  ), but it's not clear to me how to automate this robustly.

EDIT: Here's what I did to get this working on a toy memcached server on my machine. It seems to work but I only put two keys in memcached, so hopefully this method will scale ok:

shell commands:

```
sudo yum install memcached
sudo /etc/init.d/memcached restart # maybe unnecessary
sudo yum install php
sudo yum install php-pecl-memcache
sudo service httpd reload
```

php script, based on [this](http://100days.de/serendipity/archives/55-Dumping-MemcacheD-Content-Keys-with-PHP.html):

```
<?php
$memcache = new Memcache();
$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
$list = array();
$allSlabs = $memcache->getExtendedStats('slabs');
$items = $memcache->getExtendedStats('items');
foreach($allSlabs as $server => $slabs) {
    foreach($slabs AS $slabId => $slabMeta) {
        if (!is_int($slabId)) {
            continue;
        }
        $cdump = $memcache->getExtendedStats('cachedump', (int) $slabId, 100000000);
        foreach($cdump AS $server => $entries) {
            if ($entries) {
                foreach($entries AS $eName => $eData) {
                    print_r($eName);
                    print_r(":");
                    $val = $memcache->get($eName);
                    print_r($val);
                    print_r("\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

EDIT2: The above script does not seem to return all of the mappings. If I insert the line `count($entries)`, it only returns a little over 50k, even with the limit parameter set to 100M, but executing `stats items` from telnet shows over 5M entries. Does anyone know why this might be the case?

EDIT3: This [link](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewProgrammingFAQ) suggests that cachedump doesn't get all keys from memcached. I've hit a limit of around 50k keys that are returned either by cachedump, this PHP script, or a perl script similar to one in the link provided by Zach Bonham. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Found this, that might be helpful:  http://blog.evanweaver.com/2009/04/20/peeping-into-memcached/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get all keys set in memcached](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560150/get-all-keys-set-in-memcached)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*disclaimer: I don't know what I"m doing, just sounded like an interesting problem.*

Did you see this article?  ["How to Dump Keys from Memcache"](https://lzone.de/blog/How-to%20Dump%20Keys%20from%20Memcache) by Lars Windolf.

From the article:

> Memcache itself provide the means to peak into the data. The protocol
>   provides commands to peak into the data that is organized by slabs
>   (categories of data of a given size range. There are some significant
>   limitations though:
>
> - You can only dump keys per slab class (keys with roughly the same content size)
> - You can only dump one page per slab class (1MB of data)
> - This is an unofficial feature that might be removed anytime.

Effectively, it requires some knowledge of how memcache stores data in memory (which I don't).  You need to find each 'slab', then you can dump the keys for that slab, and then ultimately, the values for those keys.

There is a tools section in the article which uses various languages to dump at least the keys, but only the perl script dumps both keys and values.

Comment: The URL is broken. Here a good one
https://lzone.de/blog/How-to%20Dump%20Keys%20from%20Memcache

Comment: this seems to work only when using 'text-based' memcached protocol. When using binary protcol (and SASL) I couldn't find a way to execute `stats cachedump 1 100` (seems like [binary protocol](https://github.com/couchbase/memcached/blob/master/docs/BinaryProtocol.md#0x10-stat) spec doesn't support passing parameters to `stats` after `cachedump`)

Answer (score 9):

#### memccat

Here is the script which I'm using to dump all the objects into corresponding files:

```
while read -r key; do
    [ -f "$key" ] || echo "get $key" | nc localhost 11211 > "$key.dump";
done < <(memcdump --server localhost)
```

It uses `memcdump` command which should be part of memcached utils.

For compressed objects, see: [How to dump a compressed object for given key from Memcache?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49077688/55075)

#### memcdump

To dump a list of keys from a server, use `memcdump`/`memdump` tool, e.g.

```
memcdump --servers=localhost | tee my_keys.lst
```

To print the value of one item, use `netcat`:

```
echo "get 13456_-cache-some_object" | nc localhost 11211
```

To dump all objects into the screen via `memcdump`/`memdump` and `netcat`:

```
memcdump --servers=localhost | xargs -L1 -I% sh -c 'echo "get %" | nc localhost 11211'
```

#### memcached-tool

In the recent version of `memcached` there is also **`memcached-tool`** command, e.g.

```
memcached-tool localhost:11211 dump | less # dumps keys and values
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a hardcoded limit of 2MB for the dump of a slab. Unless you rewrite the do_item_cachedump, you will not be able to get all keys out.

Answer (score 3):

I used this bash script

```
#!/bin/sh
MESSAGE=`memdump --servers="127.0.0.1"`
while read -r line; do
    echo $line
    VALUE=`echo "get $line" | nc 127.0.0.1 11211`
    echo $VALUE
done <<< "$MESSAGE"
```

just replace IP / port if necessary

Comment: The binary may be named `memcdump` instead of `memdump` on your distro.

Comment: memdump: invalid option -- '-'

Comment: @RossRogers Yeap, `memcdump` in debian.  To install: `apt install libmemcached-tools`

Answer (score 1):

#### Bash

Using Bash and save into the file:

```
exec {memcache}<>/dev/tcp/localhost/11211
printf "stats items\nquit\n" >&${memcache}
cat <&${memcache} > myfile.txt
```

Related: [Writing a Redis client in pure bash](http://milhouseonsoftware.com/2015/07/27/writing-a-redis-client-in-pure-bash-part-1/) (it's Redis, but very similar approach)

Comment: this dumps only statistics but is useful as well