# How Spymemcache client use UDP?

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached

As it is seen that the Spymemcache client use TCP connection to connect with Memcached server as default. I want to use UDP instead of TCP. I think Facebook use UDP to get() requests from Memcached.
Any one know how to use UDP with SpyMemcache ?